# Opening phone application

Tags: ios, xcode

This is most likely a very obvious answer, but I am just not seeing it.  I want to open the phone application when I click a button.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://???????"]];
```

That line of code should do it.  The problem is, depending on what happens in the app, I want it to dial a different number.  I made a string variable, and I want to put it into the space with the ???

Something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://(myPhoneNumberString)"]];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation.

Something like that will work:

```
[ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"tel://%@", myPhoneNumberStringVar ]
```

String format is basically the same as in the `printf` C function, with the additional `%@` format, used to print object representations.